# What is Julia's equivalent of R's which?

Tags: r, julia

In Rb given a vector `x` one can find the indices where its elements are `TRUE` using the `which` function. E.g. `y = 1:100` and `which(is.even(y))` should return 2,4,...,100

There are also `which.max` and `which.min` which returns the indices of minimum and maximum values respectiely.

What are their equivalents in Julia?

Comment: `find(iseven, x)` (see `?find`) for more detail). And indices of minimum and maximum values have their own functions: `indmin` and `indmax`

Comment: I think you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Colin ur answer is the most complete. Would accept

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `find` function does that.

In R:

```
y = c(1,2,3,4)    
which(y > 2)
```

In Julia:

```
y = [1, 2, 3, 4]    
find(y .> 2)
```

Comment: Note that for ordered vectors there is `searchsorted`. Also, `y .> 2` allocates a temporary array. `find(x->x>2, y)` is faster.

Comment: Note: Julia 1.0.0 does not appear to have `find`, but rather `findall`

Answer (score 5):

There is no exact equivalent but `findall`

There is a comparison list of vocabularies for Julia vs R; `which` is on the list

http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2012/04/09/comparing-julia-and-rs-vocabularies/

However, according to the list Julia's `find` is equivalent to R's `which` as answered by others.

Comment: You should include the relevant information from the link as well as providing the link. See [this meta-question about link-only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/173584)

Answer (score 4):

The equivalent of R's which is Julia's findall:

```
y = [1, 2, 3, 4] 
findall(y .> 2)
```